# ajax not posting to page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax function that should post some data to another page but it doesnt seem to be posting for some reason.

I have no idea why this is not working i have been looking at it for the past hour.

**The Ajax function**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.rate').click(function(){
        var ratingId = $('#ratingID').val();
        var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
        var ajaxurl = 'ProcessRating.php',

        data =  {'action': clickBtnValue, 'ratingID': ratingId};

        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response)
        {
            alert("action performed successfully");
        });
    });
});
```

**On the main page**

```
<?php
 session_start();
 echo $_SESSION["messege"];
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script> 
     //The Ajax function is here
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
    <input type="hidden" class="rate" id="ratingID" name="ratingID" value = 
    "<?php echo $article->getId()?>" />
    <input type="submit" class="rate" name="1" value="1" />
    <input type="submit" class="rate" name="2" value="2" />
    <input type="submit" class="rate" name="3" value="3" />
    <input type="submit" class="rate" name="4" value="4" />
    <input type="submit" class="rate" name="5" value="5" />
    </form>
</body>
```

**On the page ProcessRating.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION["messege"] = "got This far";

if (isset($_POST['action'])) 
{
    $id = $_POST['ratingID'];

    switch ($_POST['action']) {
        case '1':
            updateRating($db, $id, "oneStar");
            break;
        case '2':
            updateRating($db, $id, "twoStar");
            break;
        case '3':
            updateRating($db, $id, "threeStar");
            break;
        case '4':
            updateRating($db, $id, "fourStar");
            break;
        case '5':
            updateRating($db, $id, "fiveStar");
            break;
    }

    $rating = getAvgRating($db, $id);
    updateArticleRating($db, $id, $rating);
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the console as well as using php's error reporting?

Comment: I dont see anywhere where you connect to a database on ProcessRating.php ???

Comment: Its not even that, as it wont echo the session message so i can see i got to the next page

Comment: also im looking at the console but i dont get any errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Since all button type is `submit` and they are inside the `<form></form>`.So you have to use `preventDefault()` to prevent normal form  posting.

Do like below:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.rate').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var ratingId = $('#ratingID').val();

        var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();

        var ajaxurl = 'ProcessRating.php',

        data =  {'action': clickBtnValue, 'ratingID': ratingId};

        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response){
            alert("action performed successfully");
        });
    });
});
```

2.Make sure that `ajaxurl` is correct there.(check console for this,if there is error in URL you will see that in console forsure)

***Important Note:-***

Check your browser console to see any error is there? If yes tell us.

Comment: ok Problem was in one of my Function requires that needed to have a ../ to go up one folder. I discovered this by using console.log

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comment, please check what is being returned to your script via the console. you can use `console.log(response)` in such way

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "http://url", 
    data: "action=foobar",
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Now, you can check your console for the return response.

Comment: You have to work with the code provided. Not invent new stuff

Comment: *"As suggested in the comment"* - Right; so this is more of a glorified comment.